# Angularjs TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an angular directive (angucomplete-alt) to generate a list of suggestions as I type into ta field. I have an issue that if I make the request using $http like below the directive picks up the data and displays it.

```
 return $http.get(
            myurl,
            {
                params: {
                    code: strQuery.toUpperCase()
                }
            }
        );
```

Alertnatively, if I return the data in a promise the directive just  keep giving me an error. How can I get to this work properly as it seems like even though I'm calling the same endpoint I get way different responses

```
 return service.mymethod(strQuery)
            .then(function(data) {

               console.log(data);

        });
```

Comment: put the code of the service, otherwise we can't understand what it does

Comment: you might have some line `xx.data` where `xx` is `undefined`.

Comment: give some more lines of code so that we can help you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the service returning different responses?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is unclear what you are trying to achieve this is one way to call a service:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($http) {
  $http.get(myUrl, { params: {  code: strQuery.toUpperCase() }})
  .then(
    function (response, status) { // on success
      console.log(response);
    }, 
    function(error, status){ // on error
      console.log(error);
  });
});
```

`$http.get` returns a promise which is a pattern for handling asynchronous operations. A promise runs asynchronously and return values (on success or on error) when they are done processing.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me guys. I'm using this angular plugin. https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt, it has a service build in. I'm thinking that it's already returning a promise when it's making a request, this is why i'm seeing some errors.